# Fix 4.2 Question

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

In a FIX 4.2 execution report what is the difference  between FIX 4.2 : ClOrdID <11> field and FIX 4.2 : OrigClOrdID <41> field

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be a little clearer than other posters OrigClOrdID (tag 41) is used in the following circumstances(gacked from http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXimate3.0/ ):
Used in messages:
[ExecutionReport] [MultilegOrderCancelReplace] [OrderCancelReject] [OrderCancelReplaceRequest] [OrderCancelRequest]
Used in components:
[AffectedOrdGrp] [SideCrossOrdCxlGrp]

and is the ClOrdID of an original message that these messages relate to. The best way to think about it is like a foreign key to a FIX (order) message that has already been sent and recieved. Because FIX is extensible it can obviously be used in other messages (with varying degrees of meaningfulness) to refer to a prior message.

Hope all that helps

Comment: well I was a beginner then and now I understand the function of the OrigClOrdID but your answer is better than others :) so accepted and upvoted

Answer (score 2):

OrigClOrdID is used for cancel and cancel/replace order and it is the ClOrdID of the original order which you are trying to cancel and cancel/replace.